# Can anyone explain the point of this dual PNP/NPN set?

Tags: transistors, analog

I like to consider myself fairly experienced in Electronics Design, but upon being contracted to review this schematic I'm a little stumped. This is basically the output stage of a boost power supply:

[image]

I've drawn in the red lines to symbolise where the power actually flows. The MOSFET Q2 on the top left makes sense (although there is no base resistor for Q3, which is the first mistake I pointed out. 3.3V from a micro directly to a 0.7V base-emitter diode, youch!). This is just a P-FET power switch.

What's weirder, but, is after this - the Q4/Q5 pair. Q4 is another P-doped transistor acting as a switch, but the net driving its base in Q5 - and what's driving Q5? The output of Q4! It's a paradox if you ask me. There are two main concerns from me:

1. The first is, what's the actual point of this? The only thing I can
   think of is, assuming Q4 (and thus Q5) turns on by "default" if the output +Vout
   is shorted to GND, this turns off Q5, which turns off Q4, which
   disconnects the output voltage from shorting directly to said GND.
   Fair enough, if this is what it's for - if it's not though, please do correct me?
2. The second is, removing my assumption, will this even turn on in the
   first place? If Q4 was a depletion mode P-MOSFET, I would say yes
   as this would be "on" by default, let 12V flow through in the
   "initial" state, and then turn on Q5 until the output +Vout was shorted to GND. In this case, but, this is just a plain-old PNP BJT which, 
   unless I'm crazy, is "off" by default. Thus, it won't ever turn on.

Thanks. Any insight from people would be great, as it seems like a handy little tool for preventing short-circuit overcurrent (although these days, this sort of protection is built into a lot of chips internally). But it looks to me like it hasn't *quite* been executed correctly, and it needs to be a depletion mode MOSFET there instead so it at least has a defined initial state.

Comment: Q4 and Q5 do not make sense in this circuit. They are in a SCR topology so +Vout has to be ON first. Very odd design.

Comment: A blown-fuse indicator?

Comment: @Sparky256 Great, glad you agree with me. I was also thinking having a BJT in the direct power path is probably not the best either due to saturation voltage across CE. You have a crap ~0.2V drop in the expected output (could be critical for some applications) and a VI power loss there. Low Rds(on) MOSFET would be better even just for that sake.

Comment: There are BJT packages with base resistors builtin, which are designed to be directly driven by digital logic levels. Not sure if that was intended for Q3...

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Not a bad thought, but the net +Vout doesn't go anywhere except what you can see, so it's not like it's going to be "indicating" per se. Even so, +Vout needs to be initially pulled high externally somehow as me and Sparky have been saying, so it's still poor design even if that is its purpose.

Comment: @sstobbe I've used those in heaps of FPGA designs and can confirm the part number they've prescribed for Q3 is not one of those. Think I'm just dealing with low quality design here.

Comment: @DSWG I think you are right about Q4 and Q5. If the load starts to pull too much collector current via Q4, then R16's base current limiting action will starve Q4 and the collector voltage will sink in response. (The pairing will self-trigger when a power rail is applied via Q2.) Just as a guess R17 needs to be only a tenth of R16. Not exactly a managed design, though.

Comment: Q4/Q5 might turn on with load disconnected due to leakage, but highly doubt it will reliably turn-on Q4 with a load attached trying to dV/dt trigger the SCR circuit.

Comment: @jonk and sstobe yeah I figured if the +Vout net had some potential (either inductively or capacitively coupled from the environment) there's a chance it will cause the Q5/Q4 system to go into some positive-feedback turn on, but assumptions like that is not how good design works...so yeah let's just wrap this up. If someone wants to summarise the comments in an answer I'll close it out, if not I'll just answer myself.

Comment: @DSWG I think you've got the best handle on how to write up the answer. Why not go ahead? (I just dead-bug wired up a pair of small signal BJTs here to see what would happen when a timed power-up took place and it definitely fired every single time. So I'm pretty sure that charge storage is sufficient to start things rolling. (I didn't try to scope the start. If I could figure a way to readily do it, I might have tried. But there was no point given time available.) Regardless, it's not managed. So that's a concern.

Comment: The SCR might be intended as a crowbar to blow the fuse, but then I wonder what values of R16/R17 would make sense for that.

Comment: I've recently seen a similar design as a sort of short circuit/current limiter protection but that circuit had a pull-up on base of Q4. And it did limit current by saturating Q4 even without short circuit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Behavior :

The circuit is a latch.

Assuming the starting voltage across C5 is 0V and Q2 is on, Vbe of Q5 is 0V and will stay that way, unless some other (unshown) part of the circuit pulls up the voltage of the +Vout net, turning on Q5 and then Q4.

From there, I see two possible answers :

- This is a strange way of activating an output from somewhere else, which is overcomplicated;
- This is bad design

I (and all the commenters) would favor the second theory, which is confirmed by a few other elements, like the lack of a base resistor on on Q3  or filtering globally.

In Conclusion, check the rest of the schematic for something that could boostrap +Vout, or other examples of copy-pasted circuits that do not belong.

Comment: +1 for a rational answer to an irrational circuit.